# Nullpointer in webapp on @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

So I'm adding a Spring 3 autowiring & JPA/Hibernate Data Access layer to my project which has the webapp and data portions separated in different war/jars. The webapp does include the data jar as a dependency in Maven though. Everything is working fine on the data side in JUnit and deployment gives me no errors but when the page is loaded and a call to the autowired DAO bean is executing I get a NullPointerException.

The kicker is, I did not design the webapp portion, but I do have control to modify it as needed to make this work. I have a feeling this has to do with the webapp still not seeing the autowired DAO I'm trying to instantiate even thought the data jar is added as a dependency.

Does something need to be added to the webapps applicationContext in order to sync these up? I'm pretty new at this so I'm sure I'm missing something pretty obvious! I've looked at similar questions asked but nothing seems to match up to my current situation.

**My data applicationContext**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:persistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="ApplicationEntityManager" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="dataSource"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="***" />
        <property name="username" value="***" />
        <property name="password" value="***" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="...data.dao"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="...data.service"/>

</beans>
```

**Their webapp "applicationContext (Dispatcher-Servlet)**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="...web.controllers" />

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
    </bean>  

    <bean name="/mypractice/*" class="...web.controllers.MyPracticeController">     
    </bean>

     <bean name="/milestones/*" class="...web.controllers.MilestonesController">
     </bean>

     <bean name="/resources/*" class="...web.controllers.ResourcesController">
     </bean>

     <bean name="/file/*" class="...web.controllers.FilesController">
     </bean>    

     <bean id="uploader" class="...web.service.FileUploadRestService">
     </bean>

     <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

     <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver">      
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer" id="tilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
        <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

**Their web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">


    <display-name>Webapp</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

**Stacktrace**

```
[3/2/15 13:47:50:981 EST] 0000006e SystemOut     O In myPractice Controller
[3/2/15 13:47:50:982 EST] 0000006e SystemOut     O About to call findPracticeByPracticeId...
[3/2/15 13:47:51:004 EST] 0000006e SystemOut     O in my practice controller [[]]
[3/2/15 13:47:50:982 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R java.lang.NullPointerException
[3/2/15 13:47:50:984 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at ....web.service.MyPracticeService.retrievPracticeDetails(MyPracticeService.java:51)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:984 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at ....web.controllers.MyPracticeController.practicesList(MyPracticeController.java:42)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:985 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:986 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:987 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:987 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:988 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.invokeNamedMethod(MultiActionController.java:471)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:989 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.handleRequestInternal(MultiActionController.java:408)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:989 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at ....web.common.BaseController.handleRequest(BaseController.java:32)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:990 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:990 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:990 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:991 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:992 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:816)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:992 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:993 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:994 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:994 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:995 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:995 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:996 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:996 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1071)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:997 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:997 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:998 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:998 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:999 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
[3/2/15 13:47:50:999 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
[3/2/15 13:47:51:000 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
[3/2/15 13:47:51:000 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
[3/2/15 13:47:51:001 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
[3/2/15 13:47:51:001 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[3/2/15 13:47:51:002 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[3/2/15 13:47:51:002 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[3/2/15 13:47:51:002 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[3/2/15 13:47:51:003 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[3/2/15 13:47:51:003 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[3/2/15 13:47:51:004 EST] 0000006e SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)
```

Comment: Could you please post the full stack trace of your error

Answer (score 0):

The application started without error which means no dependency issue. When the controller call is made its calling the autowire variable, so the problem is how that variable is create. check the constructor and check if the variable autowired class is annotated as well. e.g

```
@Component
public class className{}
```

or

```
@Service
public class className{}
```

Comment: I made a good number of changes to my app. Some of the annotations were off, I believe they're as they should be at the moment. The JUnit test still works just fine but now its error on autowiring the bean itself so I'm wondering what I'm missing. Let me lay it out for you the way it's currently set up:

Comment: Duplicate - Editing to come

Comment: Ok so I've got : 

    Data Zone jar:

Entity (@Component)
DAO (@Component)
DAO Interface (No annotations)
ServicetoDAO (@Component, @Service & Autowires the DAO Interface)
ServicetoDAO Interface (@Transactional)

App Zone war:(Data zone jar is included)

ControllerClass (@Controller & autowires the ServicetoDAO Interface)

Comment: It is hard to find out the specific point of entry of this error. So my advice to you is start this project from scratch (only the configuration part not whole project ) and start adding each element see when the error occurs and fix it